# How to Change Facebook Share Button to Image?

Tags: facebook, html

Using an HTML5 code of Facebook share, this gives us the following code:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

Is there a way to change the image that I like?

I also tried the link option but there's still seems no way to add a custom image:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="link"></div>
```

Comment: You can change from here  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: you can use this link to create it for different format http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/

Comment: you can get ready-made url for ur page which you want to share using facebook then use that url with image button you want .

Comment: @ShibinRagh My question is if I can use my own image. I am already using that link.

Answer (score 4):

Click the share button, copy the address bar, and then paste that into the URL section below.

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:window.open('URL','title','width=500,height=300')">
<img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

Now you can put anything between to the  tags and clicking it will open to share.

Answer (score -2):

Nice... Everything working fine but you just need to do dynamic your slug or image name which you want to share in url.